# Java Sorted String Permutation with certain limit

Tags: java, string, permutation

I've browsed all method here about Permutation String, I've a close one, but it still didn't work as my expectation. How do I produce an output from this input:
input: 5, output: display String combination from `a` through `zzzzz`.
if I put 6 as input, it will have output from `a` from `zzzzzz`.

Is there a way here?
I've found out that if I put 3, I should work with 3 loops, 6 inputs mean 6 loops, but mine still static, not dynamic. I mean I couldn't make 3 loops by 3 input.

Here's my current code:

```
String pattern = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";  
String s;  
for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {  
  for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length(); j++) {  
    for (int k = 0; k < pattern.length(); k++) {  
      s = pattern.charAt(i) + "" + pattern.charAt(j) + "" + pattern.charAt(k);  
      System.out.println(s);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

*Edit: * My code above straightly display 5 length, which is I want it start from 1 length through 5 (input).

Comment: you changed your question. my solution is working for your original post

Comment: check my edited code for your edited question.

Comment: It is unclear what you want in a number of respects, but drastically changing the meaning of the question makes it even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as you expected. But again keep in mind what Stephen C said.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(1, "a");
    myMap.put(2, "b");
    myMap.put(3, "c");
    myMap.put(4, "d");
    myMap.put(5, "e");
    myMap.put(6, "f");
    myMap.put(7, "g");
    myMap.put(8, "h");
    myMap.put(9, "i");
    myMap.put(10, "j");
    myMap.put(11, "k");
    myMap.put(12, "l");
    myMap.put(13, "m");
    myMap.put(14, "n");
    myMap.put(15, "o");
    myMap.put(16, "p");
    myMap.put(17, "q");
    myMap.put(18, "r");
    myMap.put(19, "s");
    myMap.put(20, "t");
    myMap.put(21, "u");
    myMap.put(22, "v");
    myMap.put(23, "w");
    myMap.put(24, "x");
    myMap.put(25, "y");
    myMap.put(26, "z");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter limit here [input type: integer]\n");
    int lim = in.nextInt();
    String[] arr = new String[26 * lim];
    int i = 0;
    int j = lim;
    int k = 1;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        while (lim > 0) {
            arr[i] = myMap.get(k);
            lim--;
            i++;
        }
        lim = j;
        k++;
    }
    print_nCr(arr,arr.length, lim);
}

public static final void print_nCr(String[] arr,final int n, final int r) {
    int[] res = new int[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i] = i + 1;
    }
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[res[i]-1]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        done = getNext(res, n, r);
    }
}
public static final boolean getNext(final int[] num, final int n, final int r) {
    int target = r - 1;
    num[target]++;
    if (num[target] > ((n - (r - target)) + 1)) {
        while (num[target] > ((n - (r - target)))) {
            target--;
            if (target < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (target < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        num[target]++;
        for (int i = target + 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = num[i - 1] + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Here is the answer for your edited question. Try this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(1, "a");
    myMap.put(2, "b");
    myMap.put(3, "c");
    myMap.put(4, "d");
    myMap.put(5, "e");
    myMap.put(6, "f");
    myMap.put(7, "g");
    myMap.put(8, "h");
    myMap.put(9, "i");
    myMap.put(10, "j");
    myMap.put(11, "k");
    myMap.put(12, "l");
    myMap.put(13, "m");
    myMap.put(14, "n");
    myMap.put(15, "o");
    myMap.put(16, "p");
    myMap.put(17, "q");
    myMap.put(18, "r");
    myMap.put(19, "s");
    myMap.put(20, "t");
    myMap.put(21, "u");
    myMap.put(22, "v");
    myMap.put(23, "w");
    myMap.put(24, "x");
    myMap.put(25, "y");
    myMap.put(26, "z");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter limit here [input type: integer]\n");
    int lim = in.nextInt();
    String[] arr;
    for(int x=1;x<lim+1;x++){
        arr= new String[26 * x];
        int i = 0;
        int j = x;
        int k = 1;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            while (x > 0) {
                arr[i] = myMap.get(k);
                x--;
                i++;
            }
            x = j;
            k++;
        }
        print_nCr(arr,arr.length, x);

    }

}

public static final void print_nCr(String[] arr,final int n, final int r) {
    int[] res = new int[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i] = i + 1;
    }
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[res[i]-1]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        done = getNext(res, n, r);
    }
}
public static final boolean getNext(final int[] num, final int n, final int r) {
    int target = r - 1;
    num[target]++;
    if (num[target] > ((n - (r - target)) + 1)) {
        while (num[target] > ((n - (r - target)))) {
            target--;
            if (target < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (target < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        num[target]++;
        for (int i = target + 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = num[i - 1] + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: My solution is working for original question only.

Comment: Check my Edited code for edited question

Comment: God this is what I'm trying to make, I spent a day just to try how do I travel from a through z, then reset z into a and add a to left side so it will become aa. I only manage it until 2 digit since I only manipulate String. I couldn't keep up with hints everyone gave me here, my mind just can't catch it :(. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I don't see the point of the `Map`.  If you are worried about efficiency, the OP's `ALPHABET.charAt(i)` is faster.  And fastest is `(char)(i + 'A')`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is a "learning exercise"  not a real programming problem.  (Nobody in their right mind would attempt to write `26^6` (that's 308 million) lines to standard output ...)

So here's a hint:

- Use recursion, and a StringBuilder or a `char[]`.

---

I should also add that this is not a *permutation* problem.  It is a *combination* problem.  And there is no *sorting* going on here.  Rather the strings are generated *in order*.

Answer (score 1):

First, let see what your current code does:

You have integers `i`,`j` and `k`, which all start at 0. The integer `i` corresponds to the letter in the `pattern` variable which you will use at that the first position of your string. The integer `j` corresponds to the second position, and `k` corresponds to the third.

Then your loop modifies the values of `i`,`j` and `k` in the following order:

```
i=0, j=0, k=0 => corresponds to "aaa"
i=0, j=0, k=1 => corresponds to "aab"
i=0, j=0, k=2 => corresponds to "aac"
```

This continues until

```
i=0, j=0, k=25 => corresponds to "aaz"
i=0, j=1, k=0  => corresponds to "aba"
```

Where we see `j` increment by one and `k` reset back to 0. Similarly, when after `j`=25 and `k`=25, we'll increment `i` by one, and reset both `j` and `k` to 0. Then we start incrementing `k` again. It similar to our decimal notation where after 199 we get 200.

So to apply this to a changing length, we need a way to store the variables in a dynamic way. The best tool for this would be an integer array.

So imagine an integer array `int idx[]`. Its length depends on your input. You can initialize it like so:

```
int idx[] = new int[n];//where n is the length of the generated strings
```

Now we'll use `idx` to store integers like `i`,`j` and `k`, and they'll correspond to the character used for the generated string. For example, if the `idx` array is of length 6 and has the values [0,0,2,4,25,25], it will correspond to the string "aacezz".

To generate all the possible strings, start all values of `idx` at 0 (that corresponds to "aaaaaa"), then create a while loop. At each iteration you "increment" the values of `idx` in to get the next generated string. Here's how the basic structure would look like

```
while(/*has more to generate */){
    int i = n - 1;//end of the array
    //decrement i until we see idx[i] != 25 -> Need a loop here!
    //increment idx[i]
    //reset to zero everything to the right of idx[i]. -> Need another loop here!
}
```

Note that I did not put in the code - just descriptions of what should happen in java comments. You should be able to fill in the rest.

Good luck!

Comment: Umm, a little edit here, what if I want it starts from a through zzzzz?

Comment: That's a bit harder. My initial guess would be, you add a space (" ") to the pattern string, so that 0 represents the space, then after incrementing, instead of resetting everything to the right to zero, you, you reset it to 1. I think that should work, though you'd have to test it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample for recursive pattern using two methods calling each other.

```
private String pattern = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
private int numChar = 3;

public void permutateY(String prefix, int charPos, int patternPos) {
    if (patternPos>=pattern.length()) return;

    if (prefix == null) {
        permutateX(String.valueOf(pattern.charAt(patternPos)), charPos+1, 0);
    } else {
        permutateX(prefix + String.valueOf(pattern.charAt(patternPos)), charPos+1, 0);
    }
    permutateY(prefix, charPos, patternPos+1);
}

public void permutateX(String combi, int charPos, int patternPos) {
    if (charPos < numChar) {
        permutateY(combi, charPos, 0);
    } else {
        System.out.println(combi);
    }
}
```

However, I'm totally agree with @Stephen C, its insane to print out 26^6 :p